# В полном тупике, __init__() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: pygame

При нажатии на кнопку L Ctrl выбрасывает ошибку. Вроде бы правильно передаю параметры, в чем причина? Понимаю что закидаете помидорами, но подскажите в какую сторону думать.

```
  File "C:/Users/Andrei/PycharmProjects/educational-tasks/Funny_сrab/funny_crab.py", line 81, in <module>
    shells.append(ammo((round(position_x + widht_object // 2), round(position_y + height_object // 2)), 5, (0, 0, 0), orient))
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'orient'
```

Код:

````
import pygame

pygame.init()
window_width = 768
window_height = 600
widht_object = 64
height_object = 64
speed_object = 2
isJump = False
jump_count = 8
move_object = False
animCount = 0
last_move = True
shells = []
position_x = (window_width - widht_object)
position_y = window_height - height_object
fps = pygame.time.Clock()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Funny crab")

walk_object = [pygame.image.load('files/crabs-1.png.png'), pygame.image.load('files/crabs-2.png.png'),
               pygame.image.load('files/crabs-3.png.png'), pygame.image.load('files/crabs-4.png.png'),
               pygame.image.load('files/crabs-5.png.png'), pygame.image.load('files/crabs-6.png.png'),
               pygame.image.load('files/crabs-7.png.png'), pygame.image.load('files/crabs-8.png.png'),
               pygame.image.load('files/crabs-9.png.png'), pygame.image.load('files/crabs-10.png.png'),
               pygame.image.load('files/crabs-11.png.png'), pygame.image.load('files/crabs-12.png.png'),
               pygame.image.load('files/crabs-13.png.png'), pygame.image.load('files/crabs-14.png.png')]
objectStand = pygame.image.load('files/crabs-1.png.png')
background = pygame.image.load('files/background.png')


class ammo():
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, color, orient):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.orient = orient
        self.velocity = 5 * orient

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius)


def draw_window():
    global animCount
    win.blit(pygame.transform.scale(background, (window_width, window_height)), (0, 0))
    if animCount + 1 >= 60:
        animCount = 0
    if move_left:
        win.blit(pygame.transform.scale(walk_object[animCount // 5], (64, 64)), (position_x, position_y))
        animCount += 1
    elif move_right:
        win.blit(pygame.transform.scale(walk_object[animCount // 5], (64, 64)), (position_x, position_y))
        animCount += 1
    else:
        win.blit(pygame.transform.scale(objectStand, (64, 64)), (position_x, position_y))
    for shell in shells:
        shell.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()


run = True
while run:
    fps.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    for shell in shells:
        if 0 < shell.x < window_width:
            shell.x += shell.velocity
        else:
            shells.pop(shells.index(shell))
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_RCTRL]:
        if last_move == True:
            orient = 1
        else:
            orient = -1
        if len(shells) <= 3:
            shells.append(ammo((round(position_x + widht_object // 2), round(position_y + height_object // 2)), 5, (0, 0, 0), orient))
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and position_x > 0:
        position_x -= speed_object
        move_left = True
        move_right = False
        last_move = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and position_x < (window_width - widht_object):
        position_x += speed_object
        move_left = False
        move_right = True
        last_move = True
    else:
        move_left = False
        move_right = False
        animCount = 0
    if not (isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
    else:
        if jump_count >= -8:
            if jump_count < 0:
                position_y += (jump_count ** 2) / 2
            else:
                position_y -= (jump_count ** 2) / 2
            jump_count -= 1
        else:
            isJump = False
            jump_count = 8
    draw_window()
pygame.quit()```
````

Comment: Переменная orient не в той области видимости, ее надо объявить на том же уровне, или выше, что и ваш shells.append, например, до if last_move: ( писать == True, совершенно не обязательно)

Answer (score 0):

```
shells.append(ammo(**(**round(position_x + widht_object // 2), round(position_y + height_object // 2)**)**, 5, (0, 0, 0), orient))
```

Лишние скобки были. Поэтому передавал меньше элементов